# ResourceManager and Unit Testing

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, resources

I was curious if anyone had any problems creating unit tests around using the ResourceManager.  I am using Visual Studio test edition and it appears that the satellite assemblies don't get loaded during the test.  When I try to get a resource for another culture, the test always fails and the resource manager always falls back to the default culture.  The exact same code runs fine within the normal application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had similar problems in the past with satellite assemblies.  Try
adding the satellite assemblies to the unit projects dependecies. In Visual Studio 
Test -- Edit Test Run configuration. Select Deployment and add the files 
here.

On executing all applications, dlls, etc are copied to a special directory. 
Strong named dll's may be ignored as these are expected to be in the GAC.

Answer (score 4):

That got me going in the right direction.  Adding the files to the deployment config didn't help, but disabling deployment did work.

For future reference, Visit [this blog post](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2008/03/20/tdd-test-driven-development-with-visual-studio-2008-unit-tests.aspx) and scroll down to the section "Managing Test Runs" for details of creating a test configuration and how to disable the deployment

Comment: This has now helped me on the same problem two separate occasions.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running MSTest and you want to access a resource other than the neutral culture, you need to ensure, that the satellite assembly for the specific culture is deployed to the test directory in your solution folder.

Just add this attribute to your unit test:

```
[DeploymentItem( @"de-DE\AssemblyName.resources.dll", "de-DE")]
```

This will deploy the resources assembly to the test directory in the specified culture dependent sub directory.

[Source](https://lionelve.wordpress.com/2009/08/13/satellite-assemblies-for-custom-cultures/)